# How this code returns this value?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am learning javascript by reading a book. I am trying to understand function. I have written a code according to the book. But I can't understand how this code returns the value. When I am trying to change the function value, this returns null.

Please help me anyone to understand the code of `else`
Here is the code

```
function solution(a){
    function search(c, d){
        if(c == a) return d;
        else if(c > a) return null;
        else return search(c + 5, "("+ d + " + 5)") || search(c*3, "("+ d + " * 3 )");
    }
    return search(1, "1")
}
console.log(solution(13));
```

it this returning this value `(((1 * 3 ) + 5) + 5)`

Thank you

Comment: When asking a question, it's a good idea providing people some context. This is from the book [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html), when dealing with recursion. Actually, you can find a very good explanation in the book itself.

Comment: For pleople trying to answer, the example using that function is this: *"Consider this puzzle: by starting from the number 1 and repeatedly either adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an infinite amount of new numbers can be produced. How would you write a function that, given a number, tries to find a sequence of such additions and multiplications that produce that number?"*

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is going on here. I think the best way for you to understand this snippet is open console and hit on run snippet below. I've added debugg points at suitable locations so it's easy for you to see.

Good luck.

```js
function solution(a){
    debugger;
    function search(c, d){
       debugger;
        if(c == a) return d;
        else if(c > a) return null;
        else return search(c + 5, "("+ d + " + 5)") || search(c*3, "("+ d + " * 3 )");
    }
    return search(1, "1")
}
console.log(solution(13));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had run the code on my chrome browser. I got the result. But I can find out how this result returns. If I want to change the value of `c` or `d`, the code returns `null`. I need a explantion of the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question, but I can help explain the code.

You start by calling solution(13), which returns the answer of a recursive function.

During the first iteration, it checks if 1 == 13, if yes return "1". Since its not, it checks if 1 is more than 13. It is not, so it returns search(6, "(1 + 5)".

During that second pass it does the same checks. 6 is still not 13, 6 is still not larger than 13. So it returns search(11,"((1 + 5) + 5)").

The pattern keeps going for a 3rd iteration. After this third iteration, 16 is now larger than 13, so it returns null.

```
return search(c + 5, "("+ d + " + 5)") || search(c*3, "("+ d + " * 3 )");
```

turns into

```
return null || search(c*3, "("+ d + " * 3 )");
```

The pipe operator is used to filter out falsey values such as undefined, null, false and 0. If the first value is false it tries for the second instead. Now it calls

```
search(11*3, "(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3 )")
```

or

```
search(33, "(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3 )")
```

This returns null again since 33 > 13.

```
else if(c > a) return null;
```

So the recursive function unwinds another level. Now it is

```
search(6*3, "((1 + 5) * 3 )")
```

18 is still above 13, so we unwind another level.

```
search(1*3, "(1 * 3)")
```

Now 3 is less than 13 again, so we reroll the loop using the left hand side of the || operator which will add 5 to our number.

```
search(3 + 5, "((1 * 3) + 5)")
```

8 is still less than 13, so we repeat again.

```
search(8 + 5, "(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)")
```

finally, `if(c == a) return d;` is true, so we return d or "(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)". All the loops quickly unroll again.

Hope this helps you understand how loops unroll and reroll.

Answer (score 0):

This code generates a equation which is equal to the argument "a" only by using using + 5 and * 3. The search function, in the solution function, gets called till the argument "d" becomes equivalent to "a".

Think of "d" as history, which gets updated every time the search is called. Lets now break the else code.

```
if c != a 
  check whether "c + 5" can be equivalent to "a" or less than "a"
    if "c + 5" is greater than a then
      return "null" to give a chance to "c * 3"
    else
      update "d" by d = d + "+ 5"
  OR
  check whether "c * 3" can be equivalent to "a" or less than "a"
    if "c * 3" is greater than a then
      return "null" to give a chance to "c * 3"
    else
      update "d" by d = d + "* 3"
if c == a
  return d
```

Returning null will give a chance to perform other test. The same process will go on till the "d" is equivalent to "a".

Answer (score 0):

Enamul,

Recursive functions like this can sometimes be difficult to decipher. What I would suggest is adding some logging (console.log) to track the variables and calls. Even with debugging the nesting of recursive function can be hard to follow.

That being said, modifying your code just a bit like so:

```
function solution(a) {
    function search(c, d) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({a,c,d}));
        if (c == a)
            return d;
        else if (c > a)
            return null;
        else
            return search(c + 5, "(" + d + " + 5)") || search(c * 3, "(" + d + " * 3 )");
    }
    return search(1, "1")
}
```

We get this when running solution(13) we get:

```
First call -> {"a":13,"c":1,"d":"1"}
{"a":13,"c":6,"d":"(1 + 5)"}
{"a":13,"c":11,"d":"((1 + 5) + 5)"}
{"a":13,"c":16,"d":"(((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)"}
{"a":13,"c":33,"d":"(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3 )"}
{"a":13,"c":18,"d":"((1 + 5) * 3 )"}
{"a":13,"c":3,"d":"(1 * 3 )"}
{"a":13,"c":8,"d":"((1 * 3 ) + 5)"}
{"a":13,"c":13,"d":"(((1 * 3 ) + 5) + 5)"}
```

and we can see that "c" equals "a" which in turn return "d" the value of which is "(((1 * 3 ) + 5) + 5)".

Compare that with running solution(12) for instance:

```
First call -> {"a":12,"c":1,"d":"1"}
{"a":12,"c":6,"d":"(1 + 5)"}
{"a":12,"c":11,"d":"((1 + 5) + 5)"}
{"a":12,"c":16,"d":"(((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)"}
{"a":12,"c":33,"d":"(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3 )"}
{"a":12,"c":18,"d":"((1 + 5) * 3 )"}
{"a":12,"c":3,"d":"(1 * 3 )"}
{"a":12,"c":8,"d":"((1 * 3 ) + 5)"}
{"a":12,"c":13,"d":"(((1 * 3 ) + 5) + 5)"}
{"a":12,"c":24,"d":"(((1 * 3 ) + 5) * 3 )"}
{"a":12,"c":9,"d":"((1 * 3 ) * 3 )"}
{"a":12,"c":14,"d":"(((1 * 3 ) * 3 ) + 5)"}
{"a":12,"c":27,"d":"(((1 * 3 ) * 3 ) * 3 )"}
```

and we can see that "c" is greater than "a" in the final call in which case the function returns null.

I'm not absolutely positive this answers your question but in any case I think using logging especially with a function like this would greatly help you further understand why you are getting these results.